# Blank screen with cursor on boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed **Ubuntu 20.04** and it worked well on first boot but when I restarted for the second time, it came up with a blank black screen along with a blinking cursor. I was able to open cli login screen but nothing more than that. Than I tried opened grub and edited kernel temporarily by replacing "`quiet splash`" with "`nomodeset`" but than on booting back the screen became very *choppy*. Login screen opened up but I was not able to write anything on that. Also, the blank screen with cursor appeared as an overlay on the Gui login screen. I think the laggy choppy function is because I booted with nomodeset. Is there any way that I can operate with such lag, i.e. still using graphic driver.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Do you have the NVIDIA proprietary driver installed?